# Full Words in Htaccess Regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the regex `[^/]+[^/edit]$` to match URLs and get the string after the last `/`, unless the string after the last `/` is `edit`. However, this regex currently checks for `/`, `e`, `d`, `i`, and `t`. How can I have it be a word, and not individual characters? This is for a `.htaccess` file.

I have a demo setup on [Regexr](https://regexr.com/432gp). The goal is to have the first 5 lines matching after the first slash, but the last one not matching at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the regex: `/(?!edit)(?<=\/)[a-z-]+$/gm`

This combines a positive lookbehind on `/`, and a negative lookahead on `edit`, to match any alphanumber characters and hyphens where the string `edit` is not present:

```
http://example.com/my-ur      // my-ur
http://example.com/my-url-e   // my-url-e
http://example.com/my-url-d   // my-url-d
http://example.com/my-url-i   // my-url-i
http://example.com/my-url-t   // my-url-t
http://example.com/edit       // [NO MATCH]
```

This can be seen working on Regexr **[here](https://regexr.com/432i0)**.

Comment: This works on Regexr, but doesn't seem to work on my `.htaccess` file. Is there anything here known not to work in htaccess?

Comment: Hmm, not that I'm aware of sorry. I'm not the most familiar with the specific htaccess side of regexes, but if anything I would assume it's the positive lookbehind. You might be able to make use of [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) backreferences in this regard.